# How to include Module name in Logger Output

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging

I have a modular monolith solution which uses some shared custom framework classes.

My host has all logging configuration in appsettings.json.

Each module has its own DI container created by a Startup that is registered in the host's DI container.

**Host Configuration**

```
services.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddConfiguration(config.GetSection("Logging");
});

services.AddHostedService<ModuleAStartUp>();
services.AddHostedService<ModuleBStartUp>();
```

**ModuleAStartUp**

```
class ModuleAStartUp : IHostedService
{
    readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public ModuleAStartup(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        // Get a reference to the ILoggerFactory in the host's DI container
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Using Autofac
        ContainerBuilder cb = new();
        cb.RegisterInstance(_loggerFactory);
        cb.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>)
            .As(typeof(ILogger<>))
            .InstancePerDependency();

        // Register other components

        // Store the module DI Containiner in a static variable
        StaticModule.Container = cb.Build();
    }
}
```

Then, in any class provided by my module's DI container, I can request an ILogger ...

```
class CommandExecutor
{
    readonly ILogger _logger;

    public CommandExecutor(ILogger<CommandExecutor> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

This works fine.  I get log output that includes my class name and also follows the configuration in the host's appsettings.json.

However, some of the classes registered in the module are 'common' custom framework classes, so the log output tells me which class logged the message but I don't know in which module's DI container that class has been provided by.

At the moment I get:

```
HH:mm:ss.fff info: CommandExecutor
             My Log Message
```

What I want to get is:

```
HH:mm:ss:fff info: [ModuleA] CommandExecutor
             My Log Message
```

Is there a way to create a ILoggerFactory wrapper and / or an ILogger wrapper that will allow me to do this?  Or is there another way?

Comment: What if you would pass the module name through the message? Have you tried that or does that serve your purpose? Because `ILogger` doesn't have any overload method as of now.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Thanks.  Will post my approach as an answer shortly.  Yes, passing the Module Name in the message itself was the path I ended up taking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if its the optimal approach, but the solution I ended up implementing was as follows:

Firstly, I created a general "ContextualLogger" with the responsibility of implementing ILogger<T> and prepending the module name to the message:

```
public class ContextualLogger<T> : ILogger<T>
{
    readonly ILogger _baseLogger;
    readonly string _moduleName;

    public ContextualLogger(
        ILogger baseLogger,
        string moduleName)
    {
        _baseLogger = baseLogger;
        _moduleName = moduleName;
    }

    public IDisposable? BeginScope<TState>(TState state) where TState : notnull
    {
        return _baseLogger.BeginScope(state);
    }

    public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        return _baseLogger.IsEnabled(logLevel);
    }

    public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception? exception, Func<TState, Exception?, string> formatter)
    {
        // Get the original message to be output
        string message = formatter(state, exception);

        // Prepend the Module name
        string contextualMessage = $"[{_moduleName}] {message}";

        // Log the result to the base logger
        // - Base Logger will be a generic logger so will
        //   include the class type name.
        // - The message logged will be the original message prepended with the moduleName
        _baseLogger.Log(logLevel, exception, "{msg}", contextualMessage);
    }
}
```

I then created an extension method on Autofac's container builder to use the base ILoggerFactory to provide a base ILogger<T>, which would adhere to the appsettings configuration in the host and then inject that into the ContextualLogger along with the module name so that the ContextualLogger could intercept the logger calls and prepend the module name as above:

```
public static void RegisterLogging(
    this ContainerBuilder builder,
    ILoggerFactory rootLoggerFactory,
    string moduleName)
{
    builder.RegisterInstance(rootLoggerFactory);

    builder.RegisterGeneric((ctxt, types) =>
    {
        // Get the rootFactory
        ILoggerFactory rootFactory = ctxt.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>();

        // Get the type in the requested ILogger<>
        Type requestedILoggerType = types[0];

        // Create a typed base logger from the rootfactory so that it
        // complies with host appsettings.  This will be passed into
        // the constructor of ContextualLogger<>
        ILogger baseLogger = rootFactory.CreateLogger(requestedILoggerType);

        // Create the Closed Generic Type of ContextualLogger<>
        Type genericType = typeof(ContextualLogger<>).MakeGenericType(requestedILoggerType);

        // Create and return the ContextualLogger
        return Activator.CreateInstance(genericType, baseLogger, moduleName)!;
    }).As(typeof(ILogger<>));
}
```

I then call this extension method from my module's startup class (registered in the host container) with a custom module name whilst building the module's container, e.g.:

```
public class PurchasesCommandHostedStartup : IHostedService
{
    readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public PurchasesCommandHostedStartup(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            ContainerBuilder cb = new();

            // Logging
            cb.RegisterLogging(_loggerFactory, "PURCHASES");
```

Then, whenever a class registered in my module's container requests an ILogger<T>, it will get the ContextualLogger<T> implementation.

```
class MyModuleService
{
    readonly ILogger _logger;
    public MyModuleService(ILogger<MyModuleService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Doing stuff");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20:01:34.123info: AppNS.ModuleNS.MyModuleService
      [PURCHASES] Doing Stuff
```